# Validating edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm new to android & I'm trying to write an application for a project.

I need to check whether the user has entered 7 numbers followed by one alphabet in edittext.
Example: 0000000x

How should I do that? TIA! :)

Comment: You can try using regular expressions. But since I have not worked on it yet, I am not able to give you sample here. Try to Google it up. You can find the solution easily.

Comment: @AndroSelva - "You can try using regular expressions" - but then you will have two problems ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the best approach would be to use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) passed into the [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) method of the EditText.  Here is an example use:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
    String textFromEditView = e.toString();
    validateText(textFromEditView);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    //nothing needed here...
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //nothing needed here...
  }
});
```

I will leave the implementation of the `validateText(String)` method as an exercise for the reader, but I imagine it should be easy enough.  I would either use:

1. A simple Regular Expression.
2. Or since this case is easy enough, checking that the length of the string is 8, and reviewing each character.  There is a simple utility class to inspect the characteristics of characters.  [Character.isDigit(char)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) and [Character.isLetter(char)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29)

Answer (score 0):

OnKeyListener listens to every key stroke in the view. you can use that to check whether the user has entered what he is supposed.

eg : if the no of char entered is 7 then

check if it follows the reqd expression format.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Class called Pattern in Android in that you can give Regular Expression to match your Requirements try this follwoing code i think it may work

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "{7}" );
        Matcher m = p.matcher(String.valueOf(edittext));

This will be true only if 7 characters are there in the Text box and then you can use some menthods like  "Character.isDigit(char) and Character.isLetter(char)"