# Get the key pressed in an EditText

Tags: android

I want to know which key has been pressed in an `EditText`. For example, if <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed, I want to get the value as 'a'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can set an [`onKeyListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) on the EditText, and retrieve the KeyCode that way. For example:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch(keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
                //handle code for pressing 0
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

And in your `switch` statement, just handle whatever keycodes that you need. The full list can be found in the [KeyEvent constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#constants).

EDIT: Keep in mind, for validation and that sort of thing, a TextWatcher, as nicholas mentioned, might be a preferable solution if you need to know what CHARACTER was entered (e.g. 'A' vs. 'a', as you'd have to handle the logic of whether the shift key was active or not in the key listener). If you just need to know what key was pressed, I'd recommend the OnKeyListener.

Comment: You can use the KeyEvent passed to the onKey method, and call `getNumber()` on it. For example, `char key = event.getNumber()` will return 'a' if the 'a' key is pressed. If it's not alphanumeric or a symbol, it will return 0. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getNumber()

Comment: You could also use `int key = event.getUnicodeChar(event.getMetaState())` to give you the exact unicode character, respecting the state of the modifier keys (alt, shift, etc.)

Comment: Only works for hardware keyboards, doesn't work for soft keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer here:

[Validating edittext in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013128/validating-edittext-in-android/6013195#6013195)