# Quitting MainActivity when a running thread meets a condition

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two challenges in my android program whcih are listed below , Kindly help me.

1. Suppose I start a thread A in MainActivity , and based on whether a certain condition
   is met in thread A , the whole application must be closed. ( as finish() is available only in Activity and not accessible from a thread )

2.In MainActivity I have an EditText. Every letter i press is setup to transfer over bluetooth Socket to reach PC over bluetooth StreamCOnnection.

Hence , I need to get every letter (single character) that I type in the EditText, stored in a char variable. (It should also take into account the backspace button which means that no letter was typed).

As and when user types a letter in EditText , a char variable (single letter) is initialized in MainActivity  and a running thread "A" will fetch and send value of the char variable to socket outputstream and clear the char variable so that newly entered letter could be stored for subsequent socket streams sending.

Hence my question for the point 2 is , How to fetch the last typed character of an EditBox taking into consideration backspace key to be ignored.

I Googled lot and also referred similar posts ([Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191049/get-the-key-pressed-on-an-edittext)) & [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305972/edittext-onkeydown), but I couldn't successfully implement it.

( PS: I'm Sorry that I have written detailed, instead of pasting Snippets as my program is a bit big and could confuse what my correct question is)

Answer (score 1):

1) finish() is a function on the Activity object.  If the thread is a subclass of the activity, it can fall it.  If the Thread has a reference to the Activity, it can call activityReference.finish().   Finish() is the only way to end an activity programmatically.

2)Use a TextWatcher and add it to the EditText.  That will tell you whenever a character is typed.  You can figure out what the new data is and process it.

Comment: @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
     int after) {
// I am trying to clear off any previous text if its not empty
    try
    {
    if(keypad.getText().length()>0)
     keypad.setText("");
    }
   
    catch(Exception ec)
    {
     ec.printStackTrace();
    }
    

Yes I have tried it but I was getting stackoverflow error :D
Please let me know how I could get only the letter that i lastly press in an edittext considering backspace key to be ignored

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions would be:

1) Use a Handler to make a callback to the UI thread if the condition is met.  From there, you can call the finish() method.

2) I would implement on onKeyListener for the Edittext.  In that listener, you can listen for any key press you want (character or other).

Hope that helps.