# Android onKeyDown() not execute on pressing delete button

Tags: android, methods, onkeydown

I use the following method to delete values from EditText when user presses the delete button of an android device.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
        onDeleteKey();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


private void onDeleteKey() {
    if (edt_passcode1.isFocused()) {

    } else if (edt_passcode2.isFocused()) {
        edt_passcode1.requestFocus();
        edt_passcode1.setText("");
    } else if (edt_passcode3.isFocused()) {
        edt_passcode2.requestFocus();
        edt_passcode2.setText("");
    } else if (edt_passcode4.isFocused()) {
        edt_passcode3.requestFocus();
        edt_passcode3.setText("");
    }
}
```

I want to delete the previous EditText value when user presses the delete button on their device, but it's not called when the delete button is pressed. But onKeyDown() method doesn't called.

Please help me about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in a Fragment or an Activity?

Comment: I had same issue. I solved it by creating custom `textView`, and adding `listener` to it.

Comment: Hi skynet
I'm use this code in a activity.

Comment: But I am not aware of any `hardware` Delete key.

Comment: which method is not called? the `onKeyDown()` or the `onDeleteKey()` ? use breakpoints or logging to figure that out, then update your question.

Comment: onKeyDown() method doesn't called

Comment: @SumitPansuriya - thats because onKeyDown only works for hardware keyboards. see my answer for more.

Comment: @SumitPansuriya - i think i found it. check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of activity:

```
Called when a key was pressed down and not handled by any of the views 
inside of the activity. So, for example, key presses while the cursor 
is inside a TextView will not trigger the event (unless it is a 
navigation to another object) because TextView handles its own key 
presses.
```

Im guessing thats your problem?

Link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29

EDIT:
One possible solution would be to attach a custom onKeyListener to your TextView. It is not necessary to subclass TexView like a commenter suggested, although thats an option as well.
You can get a template for the keyListener from this SO-Question:
[Get the key pressed in an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191049/get-the-key-pressed-in-an-edittext)

NEXT EDIT:
I just realized the first solution will only work for hardware keyboards.
If you want Virtual Keyboard Support, my best guess wild be an TextWatcher.
See a Sample implementation here:
[Validating edittext in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013128/validating-edittext-in-android/6013195#6013195)

NEXT AND HOPEFULLY FINAL EDIT:
Some googling turned up Activity's `dispatchKeyEvent()` - method. just implement it like you did with onKeyDown, you will be passed a KeyEvent that will tell you all about the pressed key.
Here's a link to the docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29