# Prevent other language except English in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

My android app has an EditText field where user can give input. But now i want user can't give input other (i.e Japanese, chain's) than English  language.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

you can limit the user to enter only specific characters in the edit text,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" />
```

By this, the user could only enter English words and space, nothing else..

Comment: It still pops up the non english keyboard and the user is unable to input anything.(tried on a samsung phone with Indian Local languages)

Comment: @AmolGupta : This code is to prevent the user from entering anything other than ***abcd...*** . It is not to prevent the system from opening any non-english keyboard.

Comment: android:imeOptions="actionNext" not working with android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Answer (score 8):

You can [add a TextWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013195/14955) that checks what the user is trying to enter (and reject what you don't want).

You cannot really check the language, though, but I guess you just want to limit the character set (to ASCII or maybe Latin-1).

Comment: how to reject??