# android - how to restrict edittext to only accept arabic|persian alphabets

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make my edittexf to only accept arabic|persian alphabets ,I've written this code but I could not restrict it .

```
name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String firstChar = name.getText().toString();
            char chars[] = firstChar.toCharArray();
            Boolean isEnglish = true;
            if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(chars[0]) != Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN) {
                isEnglish = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

How to make edittext only accept arabic alphabets ?

Comment: already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171676/prevent-other-language-except-english-in-edittext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent other language except English in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171676/prevent-other-language-except-english-in-edittext)

Answer (score 4):

This is a example only for Arabic

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="غظضذخثتشرقصفعسنملكيطحزوهدبا" />
```

Comment: the digits lack the arabic alphabet "jeem'

Comment: You have missed some letters, here's the complete list: `android:digits="غظضذخثتشرقصجفعسنملةىكيطئءؤحزوهدبا"`

Comment: You have missed some letters, here's the complete list:   android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ک ی چ ژآغظضذخثتشرقصجفعسنملةىكيطئءؤحزوهدباپ گ"

Answer (score 0):

and for persian use                         `android:digits="ءأآابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی"`
in

```
EditText
```