# setOnKeyListener not responding

Tags: android

I am new to Android and working through a to do list example from a book. I have one Activity which is displaying an EditText and a ListView beneath it. There is an onKey event which should add the text from the EditText to the ListView and clear the EditText. However, when I hit Enter on the keyboard all that happens is a new line is added to the EditText and nothing is added to the ListView.

The onCreate code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);

    // Get UI references
    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    myEditText.setText("test");
    // Create ArrayList to store To Do items
    final ArrayList<String> toDoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Create ArrayAdapter to bind items to List View
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                  toDoItems);

    // Bind Adapter to List View
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) ||
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    toDoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I've added the `myEditText.setText("test");` just to ensure the reference to myEditText is working, which it is. I've tried removing the if statements from the onKey event and it just doesn't appear to be registering key events at all. Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: in your onKey callback have you checked if the conditions of the nested if statements are both true?

Comment: are you using "plain text" EditText? those by default do a /n when you enter, try changing the type of your EditText to `textPersonName`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try using a **OnEditorActionListener** instead:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener(android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener)

You could set on the edittext in XML:

`android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

and then in code:

```
 myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
           // your action here
           return true;
        }
      return false;
    }
 )};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's fixed it. The example in my book was using the emulator whilst I've been testing on a Nexus 7 (as the emulator won't work for me), can only assume the emulated keyboard does throw the onKey event. Either that or I should get a better book!

Comment: from the [manual] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) about onKey method: "Key presses in software keyboards will generally NOT trigger this method" because "Called when a hardware key is dispatched to a view." So the key is the software VS hardware Key.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the virtual keyboard?
In that case the problem is that an OnKeyListener only gets called by hardware buttons. Take a look here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

The first line says: *Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key event is dispatched to this view.*

Perpaps something line this will solve your problem: [Validating edittext in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013128/validating-edittext-in-android/6013195#6013195)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get that same example to work by adding the following attribute to the EditText element `android:inputType="text"`.  This changed the software keyboard that came up for the user and included a Send button.

In the setOnKeyListener code, I changed it to the following:

```
    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                {
                    todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Don't use KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER as that's a hardware button for devices that had up, down, left, right arrows.

Answer (score 2):

Following code solved such problem:
You just need to need to add addTextChangedListener like this.Rest is self- explanatory

```
    editabltText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setOnKeyListener`, try to implement `setOnEditorActionListener`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

`<EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch">`

try to add singleLine and imeOption attributes.

Comment: could you, please, elaborate?? this is not a code generator