# Android onKeyListener doesnt fire

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've recently bought *Professional Android 4 Application Development*, and I've got a question about the first "todo-list" project(the user types something in an EditText, presses enter and the Text entered before get added to a ListView):

everything works as it should, but as soon as I set the target SDK to 16(4.1) or higher the onKeyListener doesn't fire when I press enter. Why is that and is there a way to solve this?

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                myEditText.setText("");
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Thank you :)

Comment: This has already been answered here:


http://stackoverflow.com/a/18164614/395176

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [`setOnEditorActionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29).

YOur `EditText` in XML layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Your action:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText
        .setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {

                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    // Your action
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

You can use [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html):

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        if (s.toString().substring(start).contains("\n")) {
            // YOur action
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // empty
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // empty
    }
});
```