# KeyBoard : setonkeylistener not working for EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, onkeylistener

I am created an app which toast some text when user click on android keyboard's ENTER key but its working on my desktop keyboard means when i click on desktop keyboard's enter key its making toast.
So what could i do for android keyboard's enter key????

HERE is code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener{

EditText editText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setOnKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        Toast.makeText(this,editText.getText().toString()+"Enter Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this: Filter your action first using `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        Toast.makeText(this,editText.getText().toString()+"Enter Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

use an `setOnEditorActionListener` on your `Edittext`

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ( (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) || ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN ))){
                Toast.makeText(this,editText.getText().toString()+"Enter Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Make sure in XMl you had:

```
<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Comment: ok its working now but its not showing the enter symbol on keyboard instead its showing correct tick!! well is it ok with this???

Comment: yes it is ok ...here is the official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyListener()` is working for hard keyboard not soft keyborad.

---

Helpful reading:

[EditText OnKeyListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425838/edittext-onkeylistener-not-working)

[Android EditText delete(backspace) key event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event/11377462#11377462)

[setOnKeyListener not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164523/setonkeylistener-not-responding)